# Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback, how to set track languague?

Tags: vb.net, audio, video, directx, audiovideoplayback

I am using Microsoft.Directx.AudioVideo.Playback.dll for my video player and everything went very well...

But now I have videos with a double audio track and I can't find how to change the audio track or how to put subtitles...

Could you help me please, I know that somehow it has to be done, but I don't know how!

Thank you so much for everything

Answer (score 0):

The design of this API is not taking into account that media files might have multiple audio tracks. You will need to use a different API offering better track and subtitle flexibility, such as high level WPF `MediaElement` or some wrapper over low level media APIs like DirectShow or Media Foundation (respectively [DirectShow.NET library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), and less so [MediaFoundation.NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/)).

If you expect similar ease of use equal to `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` API, you would probably want to use .NET APIs and controls like WPF MediaElement, XAML MediaPlayerElement, staying within their limitations and types of media they offer support for.

Use of low level media APIs (which in turn are all expecting consumption from C++ and not .NET) with wrappers is offering better flexibility but is also notoriously associated with need to dive deep into very small details of media playback.

Comment: What a disappointment, now I will have to study then ... I never thought I could have this problem, well thank you very much for your help friend, you have told me what I need, thank you!